# Can someone give me the rundown of this Javascript regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
str.replace(/[\W_]/g, '').toLowerCase();
```

I understand that the string is being converted to lowercase, but what exactly is the regular expression doing? I know that

```
\W
```

matches any character that isn't a word character, but am having trouble with the underscore and quotes.

Comment: It matches all occurrences (look the `/g`-flag) of non-word (`\W`) characters or `_` underscores and replace by empty string `''` before using lowercase

Comment: http://regexr.com/3dn2s and https://regex101.com/r/sG1qP1/284

Comment: The quotes are just an ordinary Javascript string literal. The second argument to `.replace()` is what the matched parts of the string are replaced with.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression is removing any non-word and underscore characters. So if the string is:

```
Now is-the_time:for 10+/+good__Men
```

the result of `.replace()` will be:

```
Nowisthetimefor10goodMen
```

Underscore is needed in the regexp because word characters are letters, digits, and underscore, so `\W` by itself wouldn't remove the underscores.

The quotes are the empty string that every occurrence of the regular expression is replaced with.

Comment: Thank you! Helped a lot.